# Delete failed exception when creating test data in an @TestSetup method

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, dmlexception, test-setup

I'm trying to create an `@TestSetup` method for my test class, but I'm getting an exception that makes no sense to me whatsoever and I have no idea how to get past it. Consider the code:

```
@TestSetup
private static void Setup() {
    Account account = new Account(
        Name = 'Test Inc',
        RecordTypeId = '01270000000MHaQAAW',// real id since RecordType can't be faked
        Type = 'Something'
    );// <- error location, WHY???!??!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?

    insert account;

    // other temp records below

    vNFile__c opportunityFile = new vNFile__c(
        CreatedAt__c = System.now(),
        Description__c = 'Test',
        Extension__c = '.jpg',
        FileName__c = 'Test.jpg',
        FileSize__c = 12345,
        Opportunity__c = opportunity.Id,
        S3Key__c = 'Test.jpg'
    );

    insert opportunityFile;

    vNOpportunityPhoto__c opportunityPhoto = new vNOpportunityPhoto__c(
        CreatedAt__c = System.today(),
        DocumentType__c = 3,
        //ResizedFile__c = opportunityFile.Id,
        ResizedFile__r = opportunityFile,
        //SourceFile__c = opportunityFile.Id,
        SourceFile__r = opportunityFile,
        //ThumbnailFile__c = opportunityFile.Id
        ThumbnailFile__r = opportunityFile
    );

    insert opportunityPhoto;
}
```

And the error I'm getting is:

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   a023900000VAQr0AAH; first error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted:
>   []

Even commenting out that entire line results in the same error in the exact same location.

**Update**

Per @sfdcfox's recommendation I navigated to `a02` which brought me to a custom object I had created called `vNFile__c`. I went down to the code where I was creating an instance of `vNFile__c` and didn't see anything out of the ordinary, and this code had been working fine since yesterday. The culprit turned out to be the next custom object after that, `vNOpportunityPhoto__c` which was referencing the previously created `vNFile__c`. I was linking the two with `ResizedFile__c = opportunityFile.Id`, which apparently is wrong because the error went away when I changed it to `ResizedFile__r = opportunityFile`. Now I've got a null reference exception showing up, but it's in a class being tested so I'm moving on to that.

Comment: Probably it's the `insert`. Do you have any triggers on `Account` that delete custom object records? Also you can use describes or queries to at least remove the hard-coded id.

Comment: There are no triggers in the application at all, so that's not it. Also, this error cropped up only about an hour ago as I started to expand the number of objects created to cover more tests.

Comment: You're going to have to open up a case with support for this one. I don't think we'll be able to repro without access to your org. At a minimum I think we need to see the full class and stack trace.

Comment: `a02` is a custom object; the actual culprit isn't this line of code, but perhaps a trigger down the line or something. We need more log details.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c Are you saying there's no installed packages, either? Absolutely nothing that would have an Id starting with a02? What happens if you go to `<instance>.salesforce.com/a02`? What do do you see there?

Comment: @sfdcfox I've updated my post. Your recommendation led me to the culprit, although I don't understand why it would behave the way it did considering that I have other objects created and referencing dependent objects only by their id...

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c Changing that code wouldn't have helped, it's just masking the problem. The parent record is being deleted before you insert the child object. This might be related to a caught DML exception, rollback statements, or something else you're doing in your code. We'd need to see that area of the code to learn more.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I figured as much. After more digging, I think it's all coming from an exception that is being caught by two REST services I have. The exception is `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`. The whole reason why I even decided to start creating test data was so I can fix this specific issue. Right now I've pretty much hit a dead end because I can't get test data created, so I can have the test methods perform call outs and avoid the callout exception because test data is being created in the same context...

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c You need to use Test.startTest() at the appropriate place to reset the transaction state so you can perform your mock callouts.

Comment: @sfdcfox, well, I had SOQL queries and some test objects happen before `Test.startTest()`, so I moved them after it, and that didn't help at all. Should I be starting and stopping the test multiple times per test method?

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c You can only start/stop once each per test method. The first thing after start test should be your callout. We probably need to see more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the long conversation with @sfdcfox in the comments I saw the writing on the wall, and it pretty much told me to rewrite all tests from scratch, so I've been doing that for three days (yay!).

Originally because I thought I was being sneaky, I created a single test class, which had all test methods for all of my classes in it. Additionally the test methods were broad and attempted to cover everything about a class in one go rather than being fine-grained to cover specific scenarios. Now everything is split into individual test classes per concrete class being tested.

After I re-wrote all of the tests I ran into a `CalloutException` that was coming from a Workflow somewhere. The resolution to that can be found in [this Q & A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136386/how-can-i-resolve-an-uncommitted-work-callout-exception-in-a-unit-test-that-pe).

Since the test data is now created per test class, whatever the conflict was that caused the original `DmlException` is now naturally resolved as well.

@sfdcfox, thank you for helping me out!